# SQL Stored Procedure Create #Table Select from #Table errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple problem that I can't solve. I have an SP that I created and am trouble shooting to get the results that I want. In the SP I create 2 `#TempTables`, I am also trying to `select * from #TempTable`. I added the `Select` from trouble shooting purposes, not as part of the final code. When I added the `Select` I get this error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Procedure spRowsConcat, Line 24
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

The entire code currently looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRowsConcat] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@AddSQL1 varchar(1000) = null,
@AddSQL2 varchar(1000) = null
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
declare @WorkOrder varchar(50),@Number int,@Number2 int
declare @SQL1 varchar(1000),@SQL2 varchar(1000)
print 'Declare variables'

create table #TempTable(ID varchar(255), Data varchar(max), Number int identity(1,1))
print 'Create #TempTable'
select * from #TempTable
create table #TempTable2(ID varchar(255), Data varchar(max), Number int identity(1,1))
print 'Create #TempTable2'
select * from #TempTable2
set @SQL1 = 'insert into #TempTable2(ID,Data)'
print 'Set SQL1'
set @SQL2 = 'insert into #TempTable(ID)'
print 'Set SQL2'
set @SQL1 = @SQL1 + ' ' + @AddSQL1
set @SQL2 = @SQL2 + ' ' + @AddSQL2
print 'Re-Set SQL1/2'
print @SQL1
print @SQL2

exec (@SQL1)

exec (@SQL2)

delete from #TempTable
from #TempTable where ID is null and Data is null

delete from #TempTable2
from #TempTable2 where ID is null and Data is null

set @Number = (select top 1 Number from #TempTable order by Number)
set @Number2 = (select top 1 Number from #TempTable2 order by Number)

print 'After Setting the Numbers'

select * from #TempTable
select * from #TempTable2

print 'After selecting the tables'

while (select count(1) from #temptable where Data is null) > 0
begin
    set @WorkOrder = (select ID from #TempTable where Number = @Number)
    print ('#TempTable WorkOrder: ' + @WorkOrder + ' ,@Number: ' + cast(@number as varchar(10)) + ' ,@Number2: ' + cast(@Number2 as varchar(20)))
    while (select ID from #TempTable where Number = @Number) = (select ID from #TempTable2 where Number = @Number2)
    begin
        Print ('Number: ' + cast(@Number as varchar(20)))
        Print ('Number2: ' + cast(@Number2 as varchar(20)))
        update #TempTable
        set Data = isnull(t.Data,'') + '; ' + tt.Data
        from #TempTable t
        join #TempTable2 tt on t.ID = tt.ID and t.Number = @Number
            and tt.Number >= @Number2

        print ('Update Complete for @Number2: ' + cast(@Number2 as varchar(20)) + ' @Number: ' + cast(@Number as varchar(20)))
        set @Number2 = @Number2 + 1
    end
    update #TempTable
    set Data = ''
    where Data is null and Number = @Number

    set @Number = @Number + 1
end

update #TempTable
set Data = STUFF(Data,1,1,' ')
select ID,Data from #TempTable
END
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. It is a simple `select` there isn't even anything in the `#TempTable` when I'm selecting it the first time right after creating it, but that's where it errors. If I remove that `Select` then it errors at the next `Select` of the `#TempTables`. I need these working so I can see what else isn't working in my code. I added a bunch of `Print` statements so that I can see where the code is when it errors.

**EDIT**

I have an `if` here to check if the table `#TempTable3` already exists and deletes it if it does, then recreates it with:

```
create table #TempTable3(ID varchar(255), Data varchar(max), Number int identity(1,1))

insert into #TempTable3(ID,Data)
exec spRowsConcat @AddSQL1='select distinct CAST(wm.WorkOrder as varchar(50)), convert(nvarchar(50), mr.ActualDate,101)
                        from working.MaterialReceipt mr
                        left join working.PurchaseOrderLine_NonFiltered wmpol on wmpol.Id = mr.PurchaseOrderLine and mr.ActualDate is not null
                        left join working.WorkMaterial_nonFiltered wm on wm.cd_PurchaseOrderLine = wmpol.Id
                        left join working.WorkOrderT wo on wo.WOId = wm.WorkOrder
                        Order by cast(wm.WorkOrder as varchar(50))'
            ,@AddSQL2='select distinct CAST(wm.WorkOrder as varchar(50))
                        from working.MaterialReceipt mr
                        left join working.PurchaseOrderLine_NonFiltered wmpol on wmpol.Id = mr.PurchaseOrderLine and mr.ActualDate is not null
                        left join working.WorkMaterial_nonFiltered wm on wm.cd_PurchaseOrderLine = wmpol.Id
                        left join working.WorkOrderT wo on wo.WOId = wm.WorkOrder
                        Order by cast(wm.WorkOrder as varchar(50))'
select * from #TempTable3
```

When I run just the `exec` it works fine, but when I run the whole thing it fails. And for some reason I can't add the line that has the `IF` checking if the table exists?

Comment: I am not getting the error.  What are you passing in for the parameters?

Comment: I can't save my edit to the question?

Comment: As coded this is wide open to sql injection. Perhaps if you could explain what you are trying to do we can help you find a better way to accomplish before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I am creating these temp tables so that I can concatenate the data rows based on matching ID's with a ";" to separate each rows data once concatenated into the single row per ID. This does work, I've been able to successfully do this with a couple of other tests, this one inparticular is not giving me the expected results. That's why I've added the `print` lines to see what is going on.

Comment: I'm not able to add my code after I add the word **EDIT**

Comment: What are the values you are getting from ` @addsql1 and @addSLQ2`, im pretty sure the problem is there.

Comment: It might work but what happens when somebody decides to pass you some sql code in your string? This has been made so generic you are forced to use dynamic sql and expose your system to sql injection. Trust me, this shouldn't be taken lightly. You would be surprised at how easily something like this could be exploited.

Comment: Actually, I am passing SQL code in the `@AddSQL1` and `@AddSQL2`. I'll try to add them as an edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the number of columns in your select statement given as parameter. If you insert clause is like this:

```
insert into #TempTable2(ID,Data)
```

Then your select statement can only contain exactly the same number (and type) of columns.

You probably get this done by doing `select into` instead of `create table` + `insert into`:

```
select xxx, yyy ... into #tempTable2
```

**Edit:**

Now when the question has been edited, the problem is clear:

```
insert into #TempTable3(ID,Data) exec spRowsConcat ...
```

But then in the procedure:

```
select * from #TempTable
```

And this table has been created with 3 columns:

```
create table #TempTable(ID varchar(255), Data varchar(max), Number int ...
```

Comment: The first `Select` from the `#TempTable` is selecting from an empty table, I'm not putting anything into it yet. It's around line 18 of my posted code. The reason that I'm creating the tables and then inserting is that I need the `identity` columns on both of my `#TempTables`.

Comment: @Mike It doesn't matter if there are rows or not. The insert + select must match.

Comment: @Mike Also, what is inserting 0 rows supposed to do with your identities?

Comment: The insert and select do match. I'm `Select * from #TempTable` before I insert anything and that is were the error is. I create the table and then I `select` from it, which should give me an empty result set. It errors instead.

Comment: @Mike Originally you left out the most important part, that you're actually doing insert into exec, so the problem is the `select *` because it has 3 columns, and your insert has only 2.

Comment: @Mike Still wondering what are these operations you're doing with empty tables

Comment: I'm trouble shooting with the empty tables. I'm trying to see where my original problem is. But when I add that `select` to see what is in the tables I get the error. When I'm inserting into the temp tables I specify what columns I'm inserting into so that I don't have any problems. The error is because of the `select` that is supposed to only return a blank table that has nothing in it. It doesn't matter where I put the `select` anywhere after the creation of the table and that is where it errors.

Comment: @Mike Well stop using `select *` if your columns don't match -- or remove the insert into from exec. Anyhow that's clearly the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that I'm an idiot. I just realized why I'm getting that error. I was clued into it by @JamesZ. In the SP that I created at the very end I am selecting 2 columns from one of the temp tables, these are being inserted into the `#TempTable3` that I have created when calling the SP. When I was adding the extra `select` statements I did not realize, but that meant that those selects are also going to be inserted into the `#TempTable3`. Since I have now realized this I have corrected my mistake and it is working the way that I expect. Now I can finish trouble shooting the rest of the code.

Thank you to all those who tried to help with this. It's been a long week already!